# TOP 1 in a inner join doesnt give result expected

Tags: sql-server, nested

Please help - I am going nuts over what should not be a difficult query.
I am using sql server 2012 and want to list my Customers with an email address.

I have a Customer table that includes a default email address, and a contactperson table that includes an email address for the person. Each Customer may have multiple contacts or they may not have any. The contacts can be for multiple purposes, and have an entry in a ContactDocumentOption table for each purpose. I am only interested in contacts that have purposetype = 102

For each Customer, I want to show the email address of a type 102 contact (the first one if more than one or though any will do). If there are no type 102 contacts then I want to show the customers default email address.

The following query doesnt get the contacts email unless it happens to be the first contact for that customer, if the customer has two contacts and the first is not a type 102 then the contacts email is null

```
SELECT C.Code as Customer
    , C.Name as CustomerName
    , C.Email
    , CC.Email
    , ISNULL(CC.Email, C.Email) as Email 
FROM [dr].[Customer] C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    Select TOP 1 CDO.ContactId
        , CustomerId
        , Email 
    from dr.Contact CC 
    INNER JOIN dr.ContactDocumentOption CDO on CDO.ContactId = CC.ContactId 
    where CDO.TransactionTypeId = 102 
    Order by Email
) CC on CC.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
```

Thinking that this was because the TOP 1 gets just the top Contact before establishing that it is a 102 I changed my query to the following, but that gives the same result.

```
SELECT C.Code as Customer
    , C.Name as CustomerName
    , C.Email
    , CC.Email
    , ISNULL(CC.Email, C.Email) as Email 
FROM [dr].[Customer] C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT CustomerId
        , CT.ContactId
        , Email 
    from dr.Contact CT 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        Select TOP 1 ContactId from dr.ContactDocumentOption 
        where TransactionTypeId = 102
    ) CDO on CDO.ContactId = CT.ContactId
) CC on CC.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
```

I did receive some help from an earlier post, but nothing that worked, so am seeking further help. Thank you.

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 will limit the result set to the first record that is returned by the query.

Comment: Don't be scared to use some white space in your queries. Those things made my eyes bleed.

Comment: Some same data and desired output would go a LONG way to understanding what you are trying to do. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the table or data it is pretty difficult to answer the question, but would something like this get you started?
In a cte:
Use COUNT() OVER() to determine if a contact has a 102 TransTypeID.
Number the rows to allow you to grab just 1 email if there is no TransType 102.
Then Union the records that have a TransType 102 with the records that do not.

```
;WITH cte as (
 Select CDO.ContactId,
        CustomerId,
        Email,
        CDO.TransactionTypeId,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeId = 102 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Customerid) AS cnt,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY TransactionTypeId ASC) as rn
from dr.Contact CC   
INNER JOIN dr.ContactDocumentOption CDO 
      ON CDO.ContactId = CC.ContactId 
)  
SELECT CDO.ContactId, 
       CustomerId, 
       Email,
       CDO.TransactionTypeId
FROM cte c
WHERE TransactionTypeId = 102 
UNION 
SELECT CDO.ContactId, 
       CustomerId, 
       Email,
       CDO.TransactionTypeId
FROM cte c
WHERE cnt = 0 and rn = 1
```

Comment: top 1 returns the first row that matches a condition typically one set by the order by. In your first example you will get the one that has the lowest email address a,,,. Try highlighting the inner query and press F5 to see what you get. You probably will be surprised.